# How to run sed command in init container in kubernetes?

Tags: shell, kubernetes, keycloak

I have keycloak running in my cluster so i wanted to change the default context-web path which is auth to somehting like keycloak/auth so i can access it through myhost/keycloak/auth/ 
i added an init container to run this command but it shows me :

Error from server (BadRequest): container "keycloak" in pod "keycloak-6df9d8968d-l7t9b" is waiting to start: PodInitializing

i believe that the command syntax in the init container is wrong because i tried it manually and it worked

Here is the init container :

```
...
initContainers:
       - name: keycloak-init
         image: busybox
         command: [sed, -i, -e, 's/<web-context>auth<\/web-context>/<web-context>keycloak\/auth<\/web-context>/', /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml]
...
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the logs of the initContainer? `kubectl logs <pod_name> -c keycloak-init`? can you paste is in your question?

Comment: sed: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml: No such file or directory  i'm sure that this path does exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main container is not starting because there is an error in the `initContainer` container, as you could see from the `logs`.

```
sed: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml: No such file or directory
```

Probably you are forgetting to mount the volume with this file also in the initContainer

Comment: this file /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml is created automatically why should i mount it ?

Comment: from your question, you are using a `busybox` image which has no file other than the ones that come with the official image. You need to pass the `xml` file to the container somehow (mounting volume or instead of using `busybox` you can use a custom image that uses `COPY` (or `ADD`) to add the file you need.

Comment: From what I understood, you are using the `initContainer` to change the xml, which will then be used by the main container. So you will need some way to pass this file from the `initContainer` to the `container`. There are multiple ways to do it with volumes, example: https://medium.com/@jmarhee/using-initcontainers-to-pre-populate-volume-data-in-kubernetes-99f628cd4519

Comment: I wanted to apply that on an existing file not to mount a new one